# Request For Activate

Tags: adobe, workflow, aem

I'm trying to make a page/site activation workflow in Adobe AEM 6.2

I need the following steps to be executed:

1. Author creating and editing the page and push "Request for Activate" Button in top menu.
2. Administrator (publisher) receiving e-mail with page link, making review and publish it.
3. Author receiving e-mail about the page was published.

So far I've created 2 users, one in authors group, another user in administrators group.

Under author user I've created a Geometrix site from template.
In site permissions I've added group administrator with all permissions and group authors with all permissions except publish/unpublish option.

I've started a Request For Activation Workflow on this site with default model template.

The problem is that my author user doesn't have "Request for Activate" button in the top menu:
[Author page edit menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz2Mb.png)

I think author user miss some permission.
Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what permissions you have done. I have created a test-authors similar to your permissions as shown below. if i don't provide the Replicate permissions the replication actions like (Publish, Publish Later, Unpublish, etc) will not be enabled. That's the expected behaviour.

**Test Authors Group**
[image: Test Authors group]

**With out Replicate Permissions**
[image: With out replicate]

**With Replicate permissions**
[image: with replicate]

Comment: I need a "Request forActivate" button for user without replication permissions. On You first Screenshot there is no such button. An not such menu item in my screenshot.

Comment: @IgorKarelin can you provide some steps what you have done?

Comment: So far I've created 2 users, one in authors group, another user in administrators group.

Under author user I've created a Geometrix site from template. In site permissions I've added group administrator with all permissions and group authors with all permissions except publish/unpublish option.

I've started a Request For Activation Workflow on this site with default model template.

Answer (score 0):

The user who needs to start the Request for Activation workflow must have workflow privileges, as well as no replication permissions. Put them in the `workflow-users` group.